# Variance of integral

Tags: integration, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, variance

I am trying to understand stochastic calculus and got stuck calculating the following.

I need the distribution of a zero bond under the black model, so I am deriving the variance using the second moment of $\int_{t}^{t+h} r_s\,ds.$

Given the differential equation for $r_t$ (with $W$ standard Brownian motion):
$$dr_t \;=\; \mu dt + \sigma dWt^Q,$$

I want to calculate

$$\mathbb{E}_t^Q\left[\,\left(\int_{t}^{t+h} r_s\,ds\right)^2\,\right].$$

I have gotten this far:

$$=\;\mathbb{E}_t^Q\left(\int_{t}^{t+h} r_s\,ds\,\int_{t}^{t+h}r_u\,du\right)$$
$$=\;\int_{t}^{t+h}\int_{t}^{t+h} \big(\mathbb{E}_t^Q r_s r_u\big)\,ds\,du.$$

Now I know that $r_s$ and $r_u$ are normally distributed, but where to go from here?

Comment: We have $\int_t^{t+h}dr_s=\int_t^{t+h}\mu ds + \sigma \int_t^{t+h} dW_s^Q$, which implies $$r_{t+h}=r_t +\mu h+\sigma W_{t+h}^Q-\sigma W_{t}^Q.$$

Answer (score 0):

Could you maybe use $Var[\int_t^{t+h}r_sds]=E[(\int_t^{t+h}r_sds)^2]-(E[\int_t^{t+h}r_sds])^2 $. Then if $r_s$ is Normal, then the integral itself follows Normal distribution with $\mu=\int_t^{t+h}E[r(s)]ds$ and $\sigma^2=\int_t^{t+h} \int_t^{t+h}E[r_s r_t]dtds$

Then you yo must solve the SDE and plug everything in

Comment: I am actually looking for the steps that solve the integral $\int_{t}^{t+h}\int_{t}^{t+h} \big(\mathbb{E}_t^Q r_s r_u\big) dsdu$= ...   into $1/3 \sigma^2 h^3 + (E[\int_t^{t+h}r_sds])^2$  Sadly your answer does not help me yet.

Comment: can you tell me what $E[r_t]$ is?

Comment: $r_t$ is known at time t, so the conditional expection is just $ r_t$